# Best way to implement a graph without STL?

Tags: data-structures, tree, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I have been assigned a project where i must take in a bunch of nodes, as well as edges with weights between certain nodes.

I must then use this information to find a minimal spanning tree for each connected component of the graph (so if the graph has two connected components i need to create two spanning trees)

The catch is i cannot use any STL libraries except for .

I know i will need to create my own data structures but i don't know which ones i will need. I suppose a minimum heap would be useful for finding the lowest weight edges to use but how would i go about creating a min heap for each connected component?

And i was thinking i need to implement union-find in order to organize the sets of connected components.

what other data structures would i need to implement for this?

Answer (score 1):

For union-find you need to implement DISJOINT SET.

here is simple implementation using simple arrays.. have a look

```
// Disjoint Set implementation
// Shashank Jain

#include<iostream>
#define LL long long int
#define LIM 100005
using namespace std;
int p[LIM],n; // p is for parent
int rank[LIM];
void create_set()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        p[i]=i;
        rank[i]=0;
    }
}
int find_set(int x)
{
    if(x==p[x])
        return x;
    else    
    {
        p[x]=find_set(p[x]);
        return p[x];
    }           
}
void merge_sets(int x,int y)
{
    int px,py;
    px=find_set(x);
    py=find_set(y);
    if(rank[px]>rank[py])
        p[py]=px;
    else
    if(rank[py]>rank[px])
        p[px]=py;
    else
    if(rank[px]==rank[py])
    {
        p[px]=py;
        rank[py]++;
    }               
}
int main()
{
    cin>>n; // no: of vertex , considering that vertex are numbered from 1 to n
    create_set();
    int a,b,q,i;
    cin>>q; // queries
    while(q--)
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
        merge_sets(a,b);
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<find_set(i)<<endl; // vertex having same value of find_set i.e same representative of set are in same subset  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you can choose your MST algorithm and that the output is a list of edges. [Borůvka's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka%27s_algorithm) is simple to implement and needs no data structures other than the graph and a disjoint set structure. By contrast, Prim's algorithm requires a priority queue and some logic to handle disconnected graphs, and Kruskal's algorithm requires a disjoint set structure *and* a sorting algorithm. I would set up the data structures like this. There is an adjacency record for each incident vertex-edge pair.

```
struct Adjacency;

struct Edge {
    int weight;
};

struct Vertex {
    struct Adjacency *listhead;  // singly-linked list of adjacencies
    struct Vertex *parent;  // union-find parent
};

struct Adjacency {
    struct Adjacency *listnext;
    struct Edge *edge;
    struct Vertex *endpoint;  // the "other" endpoint
};
```